# Typescript creating Object Type from Readonly Array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an array like so:

```
const arr = [{id: 2, name: "hotdog"}, {id: 3, name: "chicken"}] as const
```

And I want to generate a type from it, that looks like this:

```
type ArrTransform = { readonly hotdog: 2, readonly chicken: 3 }
```

I've tried to do something like this (and many other attempts, but this was the closest I could get):

```
type ArrToObject<T extends ReadonlyArray<{name: string, id: number}>> = {
  [key in T[number]["name"]]: T[number]["id"]
}
```

But it doesn't map names with the exact id, it generates a union from all the ids (2 | 3) - which is not what I want.

Is it even possible to create a generic like this in Typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access each whole individual object with only `[number]`, then separately extract the name property (assert that it'll be the key with `as`) and the id after the colon.

```
type Obj = {
    [T in typeof arr[number] as T["name"]]: T["id"]
}
```

Comment: It is possible to make a generic version as well: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbxgSwCYBcMATADQxhwC2ApkQEQAWIUeIA5vTAL7nb5EAzOUq0GwRjmABrGmC7cAuvAgxQkKAG4AUFACeABxowAgkgAqIAPIAjAFY1gUADzmYNAB5Q5eVQCUaODYwABs9MwQ4PWd+QgoAVyobGgQRajoYaAQcMHZuAD581BhMbRhyjABpXDAYc3QwROSEZThVSvR6URp6RUUiDvp8Xu1uHX0jUwtIyAAzEAQqYojLWwcnZwmaEFn4JHydIA)

Comment: Damn this is good! What is this sorcery? 

Also thanks a ton @Bbrk24, your playground link was more or less exactly what my actual use case is.